# Why does google geocode api return inconsistent json results?

Tags: json, api, google-geocoder

I'm trying to use google geocode api to extract lat/lng coordinates from a given location string. However, The JSON results returned are not consistent, I'm not sure why:

- Example 1

[The api call](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=MEET%20NAGY%20VILLAGE,%20DAKAHLIYA&sensor=false&region=eg)

The result

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Mit Nagy",
               "short_name" : "Mit Nagy",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Mit Nagy",
               "short_name" : "Mit Nagy",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Mit Ghamr",
               "short_name" : "Mit Ghamr",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Daqahlia",
               "short_name" : "Daqahlia",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Egypt",
               "short_name" : "EG",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Mit Nagy, Mit Ghamr, Daqahlia, Egypt",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 30.6705522,
               "lng" : 31.2912754
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 30.6801489,
                  "lng" : 31.3072828
               },
                "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 30.6609546,
                  "lng" : 31.275268
               }
            }
         },
         "partial_match" : true,
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK" 
}
```

Notice that the heirarchy to get the location is `response->results[0]->geometry->location`

- **Example 2**

[The Api Call](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=ITAY%20EL%20BAROUD&sensor=true&region=eg)

*The result*

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Markaz Itay Al Baroud",
               "short_name" : "Markaz Itay Al Baroud",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Beheira",
               "short_name" : "Beheira",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Egypt",
               "short_name" : "EG",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Markaz Itay Al Baroud, Beheira, Egypt",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 30.9757371,
                  "lng" : 30.7938058
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 30.7921464,
                  "lng" : 30.5296768
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 30.8891275,
               "lng" : 30.6660044
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 30.9757371,
                  "lng" : 30.7938058
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 30.7921464,
                  "lng" : 30.5296768
               }
            }
         },
         "partial_match" : true,
         "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

In this case the location is not under  the *geometry* key anymore:

`response->results[0]->location`

The examples in the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) show that the location is always under the *geometry* key, so why does it return it a level up then?

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to your question of why you see these inconsistencies, but please consider HERE Geocoder for consistent results.

API documentation is at developer.here.com/geocoder
The daily free limit is 2,500 transactions.

See two example queries for your locations below:

Mit Nagy

[https://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?searchtext=mit nagy&languages=en&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&gen=5&jsonAttributes=1](https://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?searchtext=mit%20nagy&languages=en&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&gen=5&jsonAttributes=1)

Markaz Itay Al Baroud

[https://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?searchtext=Markaz Itay Al Baroud&languages=en&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&gen=5&jsonAttributes=1](https://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?searchtext=Markaz%20Itay%20Al%20Baroud&languages=en&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&gen=5&jsonAttributes=1)

Full disclosure: I'm the Product Manager for HERE Geocoder.

Comment: If this isn't an answer to the question, it shouldn't be posted as an answer.